# SQL - Select maximum from each table, ordered by said maximum and then by created_at

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

```
SELECT id, author_id, max(result_score) as maxscore
FROM submissions
WHERE challenge_id = 10
GROUP BY author_id
ORDER BY maxscore DESC, created_at ASC
```

This query gets the submission(one) from each author which has the biggest score and is created earliest. In the end, we should end up with ordered submissions, one for each author, with all of them ordered by maxscore and created_at

This worked perfectly in SQLite3, but it fails to compile on PostgreSQL as it is more strict.
PostgreSQL requires `id` to either by used in a group by clause or in some sort of aggregate function.

I tried all sort of approaches, using `DISTINCT ON` or `HAVING` but could not get it to work. Is this sort of query possible and if yes, what is a way to achieve what I want here?

Answer (score 2):

It only works "perfectly" in SQLite because SQLite is broken.  That is, it would fail in almost any other database, because it is not correct SQL.

In Postgres, you can do what you want using `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (author_id) id, author_id, result_score
FROM submissions
WHERE challenge_id = 10
ORDER BY author_id, result_score DESC, created_at ASC;
```

EDIT:

If you want the final result sorted by `result_score`, then you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (author_id) id, author_id, result_score
      FROM submissions
      WHERE challenge_id = 10
      ORDER BY author_id, result_score DESC, created_at ASC
     ) s
ORDER BY result_score DESC, created_at ASC;
```

Comment: That is true, this works but does not retain the logic in my original query.
This would not correctly sort them and we could have #1 in the result be a row which does not have the maximum `result_score` and minimum `created_at`, but rather the biggest `author_id`

Comment: @Nether . . . What this does is *exactly* what is described in the question:  "This query gets the submission from each author which has the biggest score and is created earliest."

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this using the `rank` function like this

```
SELECT id, author_id, result_score
FROM (
    SELECT id, author_id, result_score, created_at,
           rank() OVER (PARTITION BY author_id ORDER BY result_score DESC, created_at ASC) AS rank
    FROM submission
    WHERE challenge_id = %s) as sub
WHERE sub.rank = 1
ORDER BY result_score DESC, created_at ASC
```

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` is a better solution, shorter and faster -- unless you need for your code to be ANSI-compliant (which the original code is not).

Comment: @GordonLinoff `DISTINCT ON` what? It requires you to have the same parameter in the `ORDER BY` statement which does not work for me